# Two Bars Hugging Face Transformers Training

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am having problems to fine tune a model. I am getting this error:
`ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: logits. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,attention_mask.`

Does somebody know what is going on? I have been trying to solve this for 5 hours and I can't find a solution to my specific issue.

Here's my code too. I am mostly using Hugging Face transformers and pytorch. The dataset is also from the huggingface hub:

```
dataset = load_dataset("xtreme", "PAN-X.eu", split='train')

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("IParraMartin/EusBERTa", add_prefix_space=True)
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("IParraMartin/EusBERTa")

def encode_data(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples['tokens'],
                     padding='max_length',
                     truncation=True,
                     max_length=512,
                     return_tensors="pt",
                     is_split_into_words=True)

encoded_dataset = dataset.map(encode_data, batched=True)

model.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(model.config.hidden_size, 6)

args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="./results",
                         num_train_epochs=3)

metric = evaluate.load('accuracy')

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

trainer = Trainer(model=model,
                  args=args,
                  train_dataset=encoded_dataset)

trainer.train()
```